# Python 3.x - How to get my program to not calculate a section when it is invalidated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everyone the problem I am having is with movie theatre tickets and sections. Basically, the program is supposed to take the tickets entered and generate the total income. One requirement is the invalidation function which is executed if the amount of tickets entered exceeds the seating limit of that section. The program works fine but when the invalidation happens and a proper number of tickets is entered, it will calculate the tickets that caused the invalidation function to execute, as well as the new proper amount of tickets sold. Please help. Thanks!

```
    secA = 20
    secB = 15
    secC = 10
    def getTickets():

        global A
        A = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))

        global B
        B = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))

        global C
        C = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))

    def ticketsValid(A,B,C):
        while A > 300 or A < 0:
            print("ERROR: Section A has a limit of 300 seats")
            A = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))
        while B > 500 or B < 0:
            print("ERROR: Section B has a limit of 500 seats")
            B = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))
        while C > 200 or C < 0:
            print("ERROR: Section C has a limit of 200 seats")
            C = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))

    def calcIncome(A, B, C):
        incomeGenerated = A * secA + B * secB + C * secC
        print("The income generated is $%d" % (incomeGenerated))

    def main():
        getTickets()
        ticketsValid(A,B,C)
        calcIncome(A, B, C)

    main()
```

Comment: so basically when there is an error it asks for you to reenter the tickets again for all three sections, and when it is within the seating limit and the income is generated, the income generated includes the tickets that were in the error, so let's say you put in 500 tickets which is over the limit of A, it will ask to put in the numbers again, and this time you put in 200 which is within the limit, the final price will include 500 + 200 + the other two sections worth of tickets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that within `ticketsValid` you are only changing the local variables `A`, `B` and `C`. So when you leave the function, all the changed values are lost and the ones from the global space are used again.

You can fix this by either calling `global A, B, C` again as you did in the `getTickets` function, or an even better solution would be to make the function *return* the values. So `getTickets` would return a tuple of `(A, B, C)`, `ticketsValid` would take that tuple and again return such a tuple (with the modified values) which `calcIncome` would then use again.

For example like this:

```
def getTickets():
    A = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))
    B = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))
    C = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))
    return (A, B, C)

def ticketsValid(A, B, C):
    while A > 300 or A < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section A has a limit of 300 seats")
        A = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))
    while B > 500 or B < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section B has a limit of 500 seats")
        B = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))
    while C > 200 or C < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section C has a limit of 200 seats")
        C = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))
    return (A, B, C)

def calcIncome(A, B, C):
    incomeGenerated = A * secA + B * secB + C * secC
    print("The income generated is $%d" % (incomeGenerated))

def main():
    A, B, C = getTickets()
    A, B, C = ticketsValid(A, B, C)
    calcIncome(A, B, C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the same variable names in your function header def ticketsValid(A,B,C): as you do for your global variables. So when you overwrite A, B or C in ticketsValid you are only overwriting it locally not the global variable. You need to use globals()['A'] in your function.

```
def ticketsValid(A,B,C):
    while A > 300 or A < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section A has a limit of 300 seats")
        globals()['A'] = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))
    while B > 500 or B < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section B has a limit of 500 seats")
        globals()['B'] = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))
    while C > 200 or C < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section C has a limit of 200 seats")
        globals()['C'] = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))
```